# how to model variable of no interest to account for interactions with that variable?

Tags: r, repeated-measures, random-effects-model, epidemiology, confounding

```
subject <- factor(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),each=4, times=2))
y <- c(5,4,9,3,4,4,2,1,10,7,8,7,1,2,1,1,5,10,1,7,3,2,1,4,3,8,7,3,1,1,2,1,15,10,20,11,2,2,1,3,11,12,9,7,2,3,1,2,11,9,8,9,3,4,2,1) 

gender <- factor(rep(c(rep("Female",times=16),rep("Male",times=12)), times=2))
day <- factor(rep(c("day1","day2","day3","day4"),times=14))
score <- factor(rep(c(97,67,88,39,68,24,52), each=4, times=2))
data <- data.frame(sub=subject, y=y, gender=gender, day=day, score=score)
```

I'm not interested in the `gender` factor, but suspect that `gender` might interact with the other variables, should I still include `gender` in the model? I think I should right? But how should the syntax look like? Should it be the same as if `gender` were a fixed effect I was interested in looking at:

```
m <- lmer(y ~ score*day*gender + (1|sub), data=data)
```

and just ignore the output for the interactions with `gender`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you believe `gender` is a confounding variable - which it often is. On this basis alone, you should adjust for it in the regression.

However, it is important to realise that the main effect for a variable is not the same when it is included in an interaction, as when it is not included in an interaction. For example, if `Female` is the reference category, and `gender` is interacted with `score` then the association of `score` with the outcome depends on the level of `gender`. For this reason you cannot simply ignore the interactions that include `gender`.

Comment: Thank you @Robert Long. Yes, I would like to treat `gender` as a confounding variable. But how exactly would you adjust for it in the model? Would you simply include it in the interaction `score*day*gender`? I'm confused because if I cannot ignore interactions with `gender`, then I'm treating `gender` as a variable of interest. What I really want is to simply account for any variance explained by `gender` and remove its effects from the main model (kind of like a partial correlation). Does that make sense?